# How to implement single sign on using ADFS on single server?

Tags: singleton, single-sign-on, owin, adfs

I have 3 different web applications.

**A**,**B** and **C**

now when user enter site **B** or **C** in web browser then if user already logged in site **A** then i want user to use the site **B** or **C** without any login.

now if user not signed in and trying to access site **B** or **C** then first redirect user to site **A** for login and then redirect to site which he want's to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure applications A, B and C as Relying Parties in ADFS.

All applications need to have a client side stack supporting either WS-Fed (WIF) or SAML 2.0.

If you used ADFS 2016, you could also use OpenID Connect.

That gives you SSO across all applications.

Once you have logged into A, you will not have to login to B and C.

Comment: Thanks nzpcmad, I am new to ADFS, I have some other question. All the 3-application are on same server. 
1. Do I need to configure all 3-application as Relying parties or any 2-application? 
2. Can I configure all of them on same server?

Comment: Yes - 1 app. = 1 RP. Makes no difference where they are.

Comment: Thanks nzpcmad, I did it by validating login credentials in the code from ADFS and then doing same on the redirected site.